# Command Button returning error

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

The idea here is to to populate a list of a users events for the day. Allow them to notate whichever ones they want, and then create completed tasks to document the details of the respective meeting.  However, when the Log Call button is clicked I get an error stating "j_id0:j_id28:j_id29:j_id34:0:j_id36: An error occurred when processing your submitted information.".

I realize there may be other issues with the code in regards to what I'd like it to accomplish but I can't test the rest of the code to see where it gets me until the button does it's job.  This is my first attempt at a visualforce page, so any and all advice is appreciated.... just try not to beat me up too bad.  Thanks!

```
<apex:page controller="QuickLogController">
<apex:pageMessages />

    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:750px;height:250px">
    <apex:form >
        <!--Buttons to save call logs once I figure out that part of the code-->
        <apex:pageblock title="Today's Meetings">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Log Call" action="{! LogCalls }" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>




    <!--Table for displaying users meetings for today-->
        <table  style="width:20%" cellspacing="16">
            <tr>

                <th colspan ="1">Name</th>
                <th colspan ="1">Subject</th>


            </tr>
            <!--Creates variable to track number of iterations-->
            <apex:variable var="meetNum" value="{!0}"/>
            <!--Iterates over results of SOQL query to find users events for today-->
            <apex:repeat value="{! EventsToday }" var="et">
                <!--Increasing variable in increments of one to keep count of additional runs-->

            <tr>

                <td width="10">{! et.who.name }</td>
                <td width="30" nowrap="true">{! et.Subject }</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Call Log:</th>
                <td colspan = "3" rowpsan="2" > <apex:inputText value="{! CallLogText[meetNum] }" size="35"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
              <apex:variable var="meetNum" value="{!meetNum + 1}"/>
            </apex:repeat>

        </table>         
    </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

```
public class QuickLogController {

public id ActUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
public list<String> CallLogText{get;set;} 
public integer meetNum{get;set;}

public list<event> getEventsToday(){


    List<event> TodaysEvents = new list<event>([SELECT Ownerid, Who.name, Subject, StartDateTime, Owner.name FROM event WHERE StartDateTime = Today AND Ownerid = :UserInfo.getUserId() ORDER BY StartDateTime]);

    return TodaysEvents;

}

public PageReference LogCalls(){
    list<String> CallLogText = New List<String>(); 
    System.debug('Your method fired atleast. Thats something, right?');

    List<event> EventsToLog = new list<event>([SELECT Ownerid, Who.name FROM event WHERE StartDateTime = Today AND Ownerid = :UserInfo.getUserId() ORDER BY StartDateTime]);
    Integer NoComment = 0;
         System.debug(EventsToLog.size());
    //Code for logging call goes here
    List<task> meetTasks = New List<task>();

    //iterates over the list, checking to see if call log text is blank
    //if not blank populates fields for new task with list data
    //and tracks number of blank text inputs
    //if all text inputs are blank, provide error message
    //if at least one text input is filled in, insert created tasks
    for(integer i = 0; i < EventsToLog.size()-1; i++){

        If(CallLogText[i] != null){ 
            meetTasks[i].ownerid = EventsToLog[i].ownerid;
            meetTasks[i].description = CallLogText[i];
            //meetTasks[i].who = EventsToLog[i].who;
            meetTasks[i].status = 'Completed';
            meetTasks[i].subject = 'Meeting with ' + EventsToLog[i].who.name;
            System.debug(CallLogText[i]);}
        else{
            NoComment = NoComment++;
        }

   }

    if(NoComment != EventsToLog.size()){

         insert meetTasks;
    }
    else{
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Warning, 'You have not entered any notes to log'));

    }
   return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your code aims to render one of these:

```
<apex:inputText value="{! CallLogText[meetNum] }" size="35"/>
```

for every item returned by `getEventsToday` but does not initialize the `CallLogText` property so I'm not sure how the page renders at all. Then in `LogCalls` you are initialising a local variable of the same name to an empty list and again indexing it based on the potentially non-zero number of events.

One way to address these problems is to make sure the lists are of the same length:

```
public class QuickLogController {
    public List<Event> TodaysEvents{get;set;}
    public List<String> CallLogText{get;set;}
    ...
    public QuickLogController() {
        TodaysEvents = [
                SELECT Ownerid, Who.name
                FROM event WHERE StartDateTime = Today
                AND Ownerid = :UserInfo.getUserId()
                ORDER BY StartDateTime
                ];
        CallLogText = new List<String>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < TodaysEvents.size(); i++) {
            CallLogText.add('');
        }
    }
}
```

and reference these fields not local variables in the `LogCalls` method.

Similarly in the `LogCalls` method you need to create new `Task` objects and add them to the list:

```
public PageReference LogCalls() {
    List<task> tasks = New List<task>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < TodaysEvents.size(); i++) {
        if (!String.isEmpty(CallLogText[i])) {
            tasks.add(new Task(
                    ownerid = EventsToLog[i].ownerid,
                    description = CallLogText[i],
                    status = 'Completed',
                    subject = 'Meeting with ' + EventsToLog[i].who.name
                    ));
        }
    }
    insert tasks;
    if (tasks.size() == 0) {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(
                ApexPages.severity.Warning,
                'You have not entered any notes to log'
                ));
    return null;
}
```

Comment: To the extent that the page wasn't already broken, this broke it haha.  I made the changes you suggested.  Then in the `LogCalls` method I changed instances of the local variable `EventsToLog` with `TodaysEvents` and updated my `value="{! EventsToday}"` with `value="{! TodaysEvents }"' within the apex:repeat.  That got everything to compile correctly but when previewing the page I'm met with the error "List index out of bounds: 0".

Comment: @Adam The key info is the line number; check the "Development Mode" flag for the User you are testing under and you should see a full stack trace that includes that.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I could do that.  Message: `Class.QuickLogController2.<init>: line 11, column 1 ` Which leads back to `CallLogText[i] = '';` - I don't understand what the issue is. Don't lists index starting at 0 naturally?

Comment: @Adam My fault - see the changed code. The list starts out empty so the items need to be added. The previous code was trying to access entries before they were added.

Comment: I feel like I know enough at this point I should have caught that too. C'est la vie...
The page once again renders the relevant events and the input text boxes on the page.  Button still won't fire the `LogCalls` method though.  I also took the liberty of trying something different by replacing the command button code with: `<apex:actionFunction name="logCalls" action="{!LogCalls}" />

<input type="button" value="Log Calls" onclick="logCalls();" />`

But that gives the exact same result as the first button.

Comment: @Adam You will also have to add items to the `meetTasks` list in `LogCalls`. See extra code added to answer.

Comment: Same error.  This button hates me.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that strikes me is the notation of `action="{! LogCalls }"`

Javascript might be confused by the spaces. So try this:

```
action="{!LogCalls}"
```

Comment: Same error is presented and still nothing from system.debug

Comment: try removing them also from the other values, e.g. {! EventsToday } and {! et.who.name }